# Tkinter createfilehandler with socket not working

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I found a working example for Tkinter createfilehandler with socket in Chapter 18 from "Python and Tkinter Programming" (of John Grayson) client_server.py

I have tested it on Linux Mint 14.04, with python 2.7.6, and the program seems to work without errors, but ...

The problem is that: server sends date and hour, but client does not display this. I do not understand why. Can you help me to understand the problem?

Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys, socket, time

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        host = 'localhost' #socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        addr = host, 18000
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.bind(addr)
        while 1:
            time.sleep(5)
            print time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
            s.sendto(time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())), addr)

class GUIClient:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Time Service Client')
        self.frame = Frame(master, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=2)
        self.text = Text(self.frame, height=26, width=50)
        self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.frame, command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.text.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.frame.pack(padx=4, pady=4)
        Button(master, text='Close', command=self.master.quit).pack(side=TOP)

        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.socket.bind(('localhost', 18000))

        self.master.createfilehandler(self.socket, READABLE, self.ihandler)

        self.master.after(5000, self.doMark)

    def ihandler(self, sock, mask):
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(256)
        self.text.insert(END, '%s\n' % data)

    def doMark(self):
        self.text.insert(END, 'waiting...\n')
        self.master.after(5000, self.doMark)

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print 'select -s (server) or -c (client)'
    sys.exit(2)
if sys.argv[1] == '-s':
    server=Server()
elif sys.argv[1] == '-c':
    root = Tk()
    root.option_readfile('optionDB')
    example = GUIClient(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I have modified code to work without problems.

Comment: You are binding both server and client sockets to the same port, which probably doesn't work so well.

Comment: Thank you for comment, but I try with other ports and same result.

Comment: I noticed a little bit later that `host` variable is probably something else than `127.0.0.1` so the server is trying to sending to wrong address.

Answer (score 0):

The host variable in `Server.__init__` is quite likely different than IP address `127.0.0.1` used by  `GUIClient`

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        ...
        # addr probably != 127.0.0.1
        s.sendto(time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())), addr)

class GUIClient:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
         ...
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        # change port if necessary
        self.socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 18000))
```

Comment: host = 127.0.1.1, but I force same address, for example 127.0.0.1. No success. I run program on VirtualBox with Linux Mint.

Comment: I force IP to 'localhost' and program work fine. You have right Mr. Hakala. Good job. Thank you.